# comparing 1st and 3rd column value in two files

Tags: linux, awk, regular-expression, string, search

I use Ubuntu 18 and have little experience with Linux commands. I have two files:

file 1:

```
a,txt1,v1
b,txt2,v2
c,txt3,v1
d,txt4,v2
```

file2:

```
a,txt5,v2
b,txt6,v1
c,txt7,v1
d,txt8,v2
```

I want to print the 1st and 3rd column values where the the 1st column value is identical and the 3rd column value has changed from `v1` to `v2`. So my expected output should be:

```
a
```

The second query is for the 3rd column values that has changed from `v2` to `v1`. So my expected outcome:

```
b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ join -t, file1 file2 | awk -F, '$3 == "v1" && $5 == "v2" { print $1 }'
a

$ join -t, file1 file2 | awk -F, '$3 == "v2" && $5 == "v1" { print $1 }'
b
```

This is assuming that both files are sorted.  If they are not, use

```
join -t, <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 ) | awk ...as above...
```

The `join` command will produce

```
a,txt1,v1,txt5,v2
b,txt2,v2,txt6,v1
c,txt3,v1,txt7,v1
d,txt4,v2,txt8,v2
```

This is the result of a relational join between the two files using the first column as the join key.  This lists the lines that have the same join key in both files and the other fields from each file.

The `awk` code looks at this and prints the first column only if column 3 and 5 have the values we are looking for.